# json parser exception

Tags: java, json, tomcat, jar, struts

i want to send json data to my page , here is the code :

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
    String jsonObject = "{ key1 = value1, key2 = value2 }";
    JSON json = JSONSerializer.toJSON(jsonObject);
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.print(json);
    out.flush();
    return null;
```

i get this error :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/json/JSONSerializer
```

i'm using jdk1.7  and json : 
  -json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar
  -json-lib-2.4-jdk15-javadoc.jar
  -json-lib-2.4-jdk15-sources.jar

ezmorph :
  -ezmorph-1.0.6.jar

and commons-lang.jar

why i'm getting this error ?

Comment: Where did you install the json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar?

Comment: You should check whether the json-lib jar file is actually present in the classpath when you run the servlet, e.g. in WEB-INF/lib/.

Comment: @Azodious i installed them into WEB-INF/lib/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
String myjsonObject = "{ key1 = value1, key2 = value2 }";
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON( myjsonObject );
```

Comment: May be you should check How to add all your classpaths in eclipse: check this [link](http://www.ehow.com/how_4784820_set-classpath-eclipse.html)

Comment: i added the jars in both methos external and internal , same issue

Comment: the problem was due to that i should redeploy the project in the server